# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when i call this.users

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am getting error while i call push method

```
ng:///AppModule/ManageUser_Host.ngfactory.js:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at ManageUser.push../src/app/Views/user/user.component.ts.ManageUser.getUsers (main.js:7277)
    at ManageUser.push../src/app/Views/user/user.component.ts.ManageUser.ngOnInit (main.js:7271)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js:73109)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:74633)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:74576)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:75469)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:75410)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/ManageUser_Host.ngfactory.js:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.js:75395)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js:74542)
```

Code is shown below:

```
public users: User[];

this.users.push({"UserId":2,"FirstName":"string","FullName":"string","LastName":"string","EmailAddress":"string",
        "GEID":"string",
        "RITSID":"string",
        "SOEID":"string",
        "RoleID": 1,
        "RoleName":"string",
        "IsActive":true,
        "ModifyingUserId":"string",
        "CreatedBy":"string",
        "CreatedDate":"string",
        "EmailID":"string",       
        "Name": "string",
        "Email": "string",
        "Roles":"any",
        "Manager":"string"});

    console.log(this.users);
```

Comment: you need to create empty array first, try public users: User[] = [];

Comment: worth doing a search before posting question... referring to the duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

you are just defining it so it's by default the value is **`undefined`**

```
  public users: User[];
```

just add a value to it and try again

```
public users: User[]= [];
```

happy coding. :)